# what's the difference between Path.quadTo and Path.lineTo in the case of finger paint?

Tags: android, graphics, drawing

There is a FingerPaint demo in APIDemos of Android.
Below is the code when finger moving on the screen.

```
private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
    float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
    float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
    if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
        mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }
}
```

I notice this the demo use mPath.quadTo which I thought should be mPath.lineTo, and I tried. Below is my code:

```
private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
    float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
    float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
    if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
        mPath.lineTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }
}
```

Then I tried again, seems no difference, why Google use quadTo?

I heard in Game Program, they use quadTo to draw finger paint, but why?
Plz help...thx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

QUad to curves using a quadratic line (basically an ellipse of some sort).  LineTo is a straight line.  QuadTo will smooth out jaggedies where they turn.

Comment: Yes, I tried compare them in PhotoShop. quadTo is more smooth. THX

Answer (score 4):

According to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html:

> quadTo(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2)
>   Add a quadratic bezier from the last point, approaching control point (x1,y1), and ending at (x2,y2)..
>   lineTo(float x, float y)Add a line from the last point to the specified point (x,y).

Looks like quadTo() draws a curved line, based on some Quadratic function, or in other words, a parabola. lineTo() just draws a straight line.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Gabe Sechan get the reason in detail.